# flex fullscreen translate/edit "Press Esc to exit fullscreen mode"

Tags: apache-flex

in flex when you go fullscreen you see that message "press esc to exit"

can you somehow change the content of that message ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tip: How to remove annoying "Press Esc to exit full screen mode" message in Flash Video
every time when its going to full screen.

Guide to remove message in Firefox 3 flash player, to remove in Internet Explorer page down

1. Backup file: C:\Windows\system32\Macromed\Flash\NPSWF32.dll
   for Vista 64 bit backup file: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\NPSWF32.dll
2. Download and install HxD Hex Editor.
3. In HxD Hex Editor open file C:\Windows\system32\Macromed\Flash\NPSWF32.dll
4. In HxD Hex Editor select Search -> Goto... copy paste 00071B27 and click OK
5. Confirm that you cursor arrive starting with 0F 84 E9 00 00 00
6. Replace 0F 84 E9 00 00 00 with E9 EA 00 00 00 90
   To replace just type E9 EA 00 00 00 90
   in Vista 32bit you may get Access in denied error, just copy NPSWF32.dll file to other location
   modify file and copy back to C:\Windows\system32\Macromed\Flash\ folder
7. In HxD Hex Editor select File -> Save

Note: Do not change NPSWF32.dll when flash video is playing.

END.

Guide to remove message in Internet Explorer flash player

1. Backup file: C:\Windows\system32\Macromed\Flash\Flash10b.ocx
   for Vista 64bit backup file: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\Flash10b.ocx
2. Download and install HxD Hex Editor.
3. Copy C:\Windows\system32\Macromed\Flash\Flash10b.ocx file to Desktop
   For Vista 64bit copy file from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\Flash10b.ocx
4. Right click on Flash10b.ocx file that you copy
   select Properties and disable Read-only

5 Open file Flash10b.ocx In HxD Hex Editor

6. In HxD Hex Editor select Search -> Goto... copy paste 00071C1C and click OK
7. Confirm that you cursor arrive starting with 0F 84 E9 00 00 00
8. Replace 0F 84 E9 00 00 00 with E9 EA 00 00 00 90
   To replace just type E9 EA 00 00 00 90
   and save file.
9. Move original Flash10b.ocx file from C:\Windows\system32\Macromed\Flash\ folder
   move from Desktop modified Flash10b.ocx file to C:\Windows\system32\Macromed\Flash\ folder
   If original Flash10b.ocx file don't move use Unlocker

For Vista 64bit same thing but for C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash folder

10. Enable Read-only attributes for modified Flash10b.ocx file.

END.

Credits go to dbosst

Comment: Any idea how to find the correct address to edit in the latest flash version (11.0.1.152). This message is so ridiculously annoying and I always wanted to get rid of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

No... it's a security thing so you can't spoof a users machine. For example this could be done to try and elicit certain information from a user. Or make the machine look like it's blue screened to make the user power off their computer when there is no need to.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change that because of the reason said above. But if I were you, I would display another message under it that I can translate.